# Getting null pointer exception on db:migrate for jruby

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jdbc, jruby

I'm trying to run rake `db:migrate`. This is the error I'm getting

```
/Users/kartik/.rbenv/versions/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:197: warning: singleton on non-persistent Java type Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException (http://wiki.jruby.org/Persistence)
rake aborted!
Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException: 
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.isAr42(RubyJdbcConnection.java:3167)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.setStatementParameter(RubyJdbcConnection.java:2172)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.setStatementParameters(RubyJdbcConnection.java:2162)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection$8.call(RubyJdbcConnection.java:855)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection$8.call(RubyJdbcConnection.java:840)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.withConnection(RubyJdbcConnection.java:3486)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.withConnection(RubyJdbcConnection.java:3467)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.doExecuteQueryRaw(RubyJdbcConnection.java:840)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.executePreparedQueryRaw(RubyJdbcConnection.java:835)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.execute_query_raw(RubyJdbcConnection.java:815)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection$INVOKER$i$execute_query_raw.call(RubyJdbcConnection$INVOKER$i$execute_query_raw.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:209)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:205)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:358)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:195)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:324)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73)
org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(Interpreter.java:132)
org.jruby.runtime.MixedModeIRBlockBody.commonYieldPath(MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:148)
org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.yieldSpecific(IRBlockBody.java:77)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:136)
org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.yieldSpecific(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:486)
org.jruby.ir.instructions.YieldInstr.interpret(YieldInstr.java:74)



jruby --version

jruby 9.1.5.0 (2.3.1) 2016-09-07 036ce39 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.102-b14 on 1.8.0_102-b14 +jit [darwin-x86_64]

'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', '1.3.20'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is described in https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/pull/740

After upgrading the activerecord-jdbc-adapter to version 1.3.21 the problem got fixed. Update your Gemfile to something like the following:

```
gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', '~> 1.3.21'
```